# Preferenceactivity on 10 Inch device in landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape, android-preferences

I'm having trouble getting Preferences displayed correctly on 10 Inch devices in lanscape orientation.
It is displaying category headers and checkboxes really strange. See attached image to get the idea.
[image: PreferenceScreen]

Prefs-XML (Only category, cause fields are added in code later):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="settingsCategory"
    android:title="@string/mobile_global_settings" >
</PreferenceCategory>
```

In the SettingsActivity i add the PreferenceFragment like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Tp_actionbar_style);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}
```

My PreferenceFragment looks like this (i have to use different settings_keys for different users logged into the app):

```
public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);

        TPSettingsActivity act = (TPSettingsActivity)getActivity();
        String userName = "xxx";

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

        PreferenceCategory targetCategory = (PreferenceCategory)findPreference("settingsCategory");

        CheckBoxPreference checkBoxPreference = new CheckBoxPreference(getActivity());
        checkBoxPreference.setKey(userName + "_autoclear");
        checkBoxPreference.setChecked(true);
        checkBoxPreference.setSummary(R.string.mobile_settings_onoff);
        checkBoxPreference.setTitle(R.string.mobile_settings_autoclean);
        checkBoxPreference.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(userName + "_autoclear", false));
        targetCategory.addPreference(checkBoxPreference);

        TPListPreference listPref = new TPListPreference(getActivity());
        listPref.setKey(userName + "_autoclearperiod");
        listPref.setEntries(R.array.autoclearOptions);
        listPref.setEntryValues(R.array.autoclearValues);
        listPref.setSummary(R.string.mobile_settings_currentinterval);
        listPref.setTitle(R.string.mobile_settings_interval);
        listPref.setValue(prefs.getString(userName + "_autoclearperiod", "7"));
        targetCategory.addPreference(listPref);
    }
}
```

This also happens when using not the App specific Theme. The Theme i am using was generator using the ThemeGenerator listed on Android Asset Studio Site:
[Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Comment: Agreed. Without any code and such, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Hmm, you are doing it wrong :) If you use eclipse, go "File > new > other > Android Object > Settings Activity" and you get a nice example of such a thing. Maybe in a new project because it puts a lot of files.

Answer (score 2):

if your app is for API's higher than 11, do this:

```
public class FragmentPreferences extends Activity{
/*..*/
}
```

instead of this:

```
public class FragmentPreferences extends PreferenceActivity{
    /*..*/
}
```